# Is there any software (Android or Windows 7-10) which can transcribe an audio file to text?

Tags: windows, android, audio, transcription

I'm looking for something like Google voice typing, but instead of playing through the speaker and recording through the mic, transcribing directly from an audio file.

The file is in wav format, but I can convert it to another format.

Free preferred, but one-off payment sub-£10 considered. Open source is also preferable.

Edit: If you can tell me how to get voice typing to stop muting the speaker, that would also be helpful. See https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/193881/how-do-i-stop-voice-typing-from-muting-pausing-other-playing-media

Answer (score 1):

You could try Otter. It’s cloud-based and offers 600 minutes of free monthly transcription time. You can export the transcription results in a variety of formats. It is available in the browser and as an app for iOS and Android.

https://otter.ai/

Answer (score 0):

Use YouTube instead of Google Voice :)

You can convert file to video, upload it to youtube (video language must be set to English), then grab auto-generated subtitles from your video.

Comment: Does this trick still work?  I read several articles recently about Google no longer providing automatic subtitles for YouTube videos (which is a horrible thing to do to people with hearing limitations or deafness, IMO).